# Subset sf object into multiple sf objects based on adjacency

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a `sf object` as in the example here:

```rb
library(sf)
fname <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
nc <- st_read(fname)
plot(nc[1])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I want to subset my data in such a way that I could get the approximate **four different sf objects** for **four different quadrants**.
For the data which I am working now, subset method like this `nc[1:50, ]` doesn't make sense since the rows are randomly ordered. And doing so will reduce the number of features but not the extent. I even tried `group_by(geom)`, didn't work for me.

Can you help me here with this part using `nc` data as example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you assign your objects to quadrants via `sf::st_join()`.

It has a very helpful argument `largest` which ensures that the small polygons are not multiplied (but assigned to the quadrant to which falls the largest area of the small polygon). So NC keeps all 100 counties / and no duplicites are created.

To create the quadrants object consider applying `sf::st_make_grid()` to the bounding box of your spatial object, specifying that you want two by two split.

For a full workflow consider the following code:

```
library(sf)
fname <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
nc <- st_read(fname)
plot(nc[1])

# create quadrants 
quads <- st_bbox(nc) %>% 
  st_make_grid(n = 2) %>% 
  st_as_sf(crs = st_crs(nc)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(quad_id = 1:4)

# a visual check
plot(st_geometry(nc))
plot(st_geometry(quads), add = T)
```

[image: nc with quadrants shown]

```
# intersect NC by the quadrants
nc_intersected <- st_join(nc, 
                          quads,
                          largest = T) # do *not* multiply polygons!

# a visual check
plot(nc_intersected["quad_id"])
```

[image: nc counties by quadrant]

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much @Jindra

Comment: Glad to be of service! :)